# How to get variables from .ascx in another .ascx?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, variables

I have two .ascx files, one gets loaded into a placeholder within the other .ascx control.

So I have:

**ParentControl**

->**ChildControl**

I want to access the ParentControl from ChildControl to get variable data.

So far I have:

**ParentControl.ascx**

```
public UserList GetFunction
{
  get
  {
   return someVariable;
  }
}
```

And in the:

**ChildControl.ascx**

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

  ParentControl page = new ParentControl;
  string newVariable = page.GetFunction.someOtherVariable;
  }
```

Where am I going wrong, when I return someVariable in parent class it has what I need in it, but when I try to get it in the ChildControl page.GetFunction returns null.

Let me know if you need more information.

**UPDATE ANSWER:**

I have maanged to resolve this issue by working around it:

In parentclass I call a function defined in the child class and parse the values I need through.

ParentClass.ascx

```
protected void Page_Load
{
 ControlIWantToGetInformationTo.SetInfo(info);
}
```

ChildClass.ascx

```
public void SetInfo(Info info)
{
 string someString = info.TheVariableWithin;
}
```

Several users have mentioned using the piece of code,

```
this.parent;
```

but because I am using sitecore cms the this.parent returns an unwanted value because the page is not physical once run through sitecore.

Thanks for all the assistance glad I managed to get through the issue :).

Comment: The approach you're using (parent page/control configuring its children with certain data) is a very common, accepted, and expected practice.  To be honest, it's far better encapsulation-wise, than having the child access its parent, assume it's a certain type, and pull data from it.  So IMO, you didn't work around the issue - you solved it the way you're "supposed to".

Comment: Thanks for the best practice tip, didn't realise that I will look to do this in the future :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the parent control within your child class, use the property "Parent" of
your child class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ParentControl page = (ParentControl)this.Parent;

  if(page != null)  
    string newVariable = page.GetFunction();
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: this.Parent does not work because unfortuantly the CMS sitecore does not pick up a physical aspx page, I will post answer in a minute and fix question to explain sitecore issue and why your answer will not work.

Comment: regarding my comment anyone having a similar issue please read below.

Answer (score 3):

I have manged to resolve this issue by working around it:

In parentclass I call a function defined in the child class and parse the values I need through.

ParentClass.ascx

```
protected void Page_Load {  

   ControlIWantToGetInformationTo.SetInfo(info); 
}
```

ChildClass.ascx

```
public void SetInfo(Info info) 
{  string someString = info.TheVariableWithin; }
```

Several users have mentioned using the piece of code,

```
this.parent;
```

but because I am using sitecore cms the this.parent returns an unwanted value because the page is not physical once run through sitecore.

Thanks for all the assistance glad I managed to get through the issue :).

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new parent control will not give you access to the current controls parent instance settings.

You could add a parent page property to your user control and populate it when you create your child control.
Does your control not have a this.Parent ?

Comment: It does have this.parent, but the page is run through sitecore cms which makes the pages logical, once this happens this.parent fails. Otherwise it would be a valid answer.